# Upgrading HAproxy to 2.2.17 if its not in the packager

Tags: upgrade, haproxy

I am currently running, 21.04 and HAproxy 2.2.9. There was a security fix that was released in 2.2.17 but when I run the upgrader in ubuntu it doesn't find that package.

How would one use HAproxies release to update?

I am fairly new to linux packages and may be off base, and appreciate any direction that helps.

Comment: About which CVE you are talking? There were [updates](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/h/haproxy/haproxy_2.2.9-1ubuntu0.2/changelog).

Comment: @n0rbert   CVE-2021-40346 - that was fixed i believe 3 days ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This update is already applied to [`haproxy` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute-updates/haproxy) according to https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2021-40346 :

> | Package | Release | Status |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | haproxy | Ubuntu 21.04 (Hirsute Hippo) | Released (2.2.9-1ubuntu0.2) |
> | ↑ | Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) | Released (2.0.13-2ubuntu0.3) |
> | ↑ | Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver) | Not vulnerable (code not present) |
> | ↑ | Ubuntu 16.04 ESM (Xenial Xerus) | Not vulnerable (code not present) |
> | ↑ | Ubuntu 14.04 ESM (Trusty Tahr) | Does not exist |

See https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/h/haproxy/haproxy_2.2.9-1ubuntu0.2/changelog .